# verify LLVM IR consistency

Tags: llvm

We can use `LLVMVerifyModule` to verify the consistency of modules inside of code. But imagine we handcrafted a LLVM IR file. This file can be syntactically correct but I do want to run something to sanitize it.

Consider the following module:

```
; ModuleID = 'main'
source_filename = "main"

define void @gl.main() {
entry:
  ret void
  ret void
}
```

I suppose it is not right because it contains two return in the same block. I ran `llvm-as` but it went through. Am I understanding it correctly? What command do you run to verify a hand-written LLVM source file?

---

update:

`opt` doesn't crash but instead output this file:

```
; ModuleID = 'try.bc.2'
source_filename = "main"

define void @gl.main() {
entry:
  ret void

0:                                                ; No predecessors!
  ret void
}
```

Comment: What you want is the verifier. verifyModule() will reject that and complain that a basic block has two terminators.

Comment: @arnt that's precisely my question: do we have a binary from llvm which I can run and reject this module?

Comment: Memory is fuzzy at this time of night. But I do seen to remember that opt will you that.

Comment: @arnt sorry I don't get it. which command are you referring to?

Comment: A command called [opt](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) that's part of LLVM and has a -verify option.

Comment: @arnt could you check my updated question? `opt` doesn't crash. it seems to "fix" the problem.

Comment: I think the unreachable block generated by `opt` that acts like a _dusbtbin_ can be cleaned out by one of the optim passes